# Value stored in shared preferences is not being reflected

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
package com.example.shared;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button bshared;
TextView tv;
String x;
SharedPreferences pref;
Editor edit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bshared = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bshared);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    tv.setText(x);
    bshared.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                  pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("details",1);
            edit = pref.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putString("name", "These are new values");
            edit.commit();
            x = pref.getString("name", "");

        }
    });

}
}
```

When i click on the button the value of textview must change to 'These are new values', but that is not happening. Can someone help me find my mistake ?

Comment: What happens here, the new values are not updated??

Comment: yes the new values are not updated. If i settext at the end of onclick method, the value is updated.But, when i restart the app the value is not reflecting. Sharedpreferences should hold the values once it is binded right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In on Click Method you have to set value to textview like below code.

```
pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("details",1);
x = pref.getString("name", "");
tv.setText(x);
bshared.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            edit = pref.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putString("name", "These are new values");
            edit.commit();
            x = pref.getString("name", "");
            tv.setText(x);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What you said works fine. But, when i restart the app the value is not reflecting. Sharedpreferences should hold the values once it is binded right ?

Comment: for that you have to set the shared preference value before onClick. Look at my code. It set previously stored shared preference value.

Comment: This works perfectly, but the value is not reflecting as soon as i click it, after minimizing it once, its being updated, because on create there is no value for the string "name"

Answer (score 2):

The `textview` is setting the text before you change your text. So it will not be reflected in the `textview`. add this line to last of `onclick` method after you change value of the string.

```
tv.setText(x);
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bshared = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bshared);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    pref=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("details",1);
    x = pref.getString("name", "");

    tv.setText(x);
    bshared.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edit = pref.edit();
            edit.clear();
            edit.putString("name", "These are new values");
            edit.commit();
            x = pref.getString("name", "");
            tv.setText(x);


        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: What you said works fine. But, when i restart the app the value is not reflecting. Sharedpreferences should hold the values once it is binded right ?

Comment: ya, beacuse your textview takes value from x, which on startup has value null. You set value to x only on button click.See my edit..

Comment: This works perfectly, but the value is not reflecting as soon as i click it, after minimizing it once, its being updated, because on create there is no value for the string "name"

Comment: you sure you added the **tv.settext(x)** to end of onclick??

Comment: damn, i forgot to add that, Thank you my problem has been solved.